# add www to url and remove .php from url

Tags: .htaccess

So I need the urls to look like this

www.mydomain.com/about

here is my current HTACCESS code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

# hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# To remove www header
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

# To add www header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]


#404 redirect
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mydomain.com/
```

I think the problem is arising in the removing php area. I think its removing the .php and rewriting the url as mydomain.com/about while at the same time, the "add www header" rule is forcing the www in. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +MultiViews

# Turn mod_rewrite on
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

# To add www header
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]

# To Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.php$
  RewriteRule . %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: what if you try it without the other rules?

Comment: Ok that works. Now the only other thing is when you manually add .php to the end of the url, it doesn't remove it. for example, if you directly type in mydomain.com/about.php, it turns into www.mydomain.com/about.php

Comment: I have updated the answer according to your previous comment.